# Rails metaprogrammin add before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, before-filter

is it possible to add some before filter using metaprogramming, so from some module which extends my controller ?
the best would be to specify after which existing one it should apply, or just add it at the end of the all before filters

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
module SomeMixin
  def self.included(clazz)
    clazz.class_exec do
      before_filter :filter_method
    end
  end

  def filter_method
    # some filter
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

cheers, found very similar solution in a meantime

```
def self.included(base)
  base.send :before_filter, :some_authorize, :only => :destroy
end

protected

def some_authorize
  authorize! :delete, @current_project
end
```